# As Symmetra, can you move your teleporter?

Tags: overwatch

As Symmetra, your ultimate is to place a teleporter.

I don't see any option to move the teleporter and as long as the teleporter is active, you do not build your ultimate's strength.

Is there any way to destroy or move the teleporter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot move or destroy your own teleporter. However, it does only have 6 charges, so you aren't reliant on enemies destroying your teleporter to reposition it.

Comment: Ah, OK... didn't realize it had charges.

Comment: Specifically, it has 6 charges.

Comment: Apparently your teleporter will disappear and your ultimate will be recharged automatically if your spawn room moves.

Comment: @Powerlord yes I just ran into this the other day, it tells me my teleporter was "refunded".

Comment: For future reference, the refund maybe a partial refund and is based on how many times the portal has been used already

Comment: @Powerlord when your TP is up, a number shows next to your ultimate meter (starting at 6); this indicates how many charges your TP has left. So "1" means as soon as the next person uses it, the TP will close and your ultimate will start building again. Yuuki feel free to add any/all of this information to your answer if you're so inclined :)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I rolled the edit back on this because by not specifying the exact number of charges this answer will remain correct should Blizzard ever increase/decrease the number of charges. The exact number of charges is irrelevant to this question/answer anyway.